# Equivalent builds don't behave the same

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

if I build an image like this:

```
docker build -f app/Dockerfile -t test .
```

it builds just fine, but the following `docker-compose.yml` (which I believe should be equivalent):

```
app:
  container_name: test
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: app/Dockerfile
```

fails to build.  if I run docker-compose with `--verbose` I see:

> compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker build <- (pull=False,
>   stream=True, nocache=False, tag=u'prj_app', buildargs=None,
>   rm=True, forcerm=False, path='/Users/ekkis/dev/prj',
>   dockerfile='./app/Dockerfile')

which would seem pretty much what I expect. specifically the error I'm getting is this (sorry to include as code but quotes make a mess of things):

```
npm WARN app@1.0.0 No description  
npm WARN app@1.0.0 No repository field.  
npm ERR! Linux 4.9.12-moby 
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "/tmp/inc" 
npm ERR! node v7.7.3 
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2 
npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/node_modules/inc 
npm ERR! code ENOENT 
npm ERR! errno -2 
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '/usr/src/app/node_modules/inc' 
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '/usr/src/app/node_modules/inc' 
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself 
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file. 
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: 
npm ERR!     /usr/src/app/npm-debug.log
```

as you can see from the above, the Dockerfile performs an `npm install /tmp/inc`, which from the output I see succeeded since it prints a tree of modules installed.  `/tmp/inc` is created by the Dockerfile command shown below as successful:

```
Step 8/11 : ADD inc /tmp/inc
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fce607bb13ca
```

and I note that the `app/npm-debug.log` was not written to, nor is there a log file in the directory where I ran docker compose.

what could be the issue here? why does it build ok manually but not with docker-compose?

*** Addendum I ***

in my continuing efforts to figure it out, I added a directory listing before the Dockerfile executes the npm install...

```
Step 9/13 : RUN ls -alF
 ---> Running in ac0c62b7da93
total 28
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Mar 19 07:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4096 Mar 19 07:01 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  722 Mar 19 05:48 config.json
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 3786 Mar 19 05:48 index.js
drwxr-xr-x 119 root root 4096 Mar 17 18:57 node_modules/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 2910 Mar 17 20:51 npm-debug.log
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  416 Mar 19 06:39 package.json
```

...and, most interestingly, there is already a `node_modules` directory there!! that means the problem is that docker-compose is not honouring the `.dockerignore` file (which prevents copying `**/node_modules` into the context)

so is there some special voodoo I have to perform for the build to generate the context properly?

*** Addendum II ***

here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
EXPOSE 8000
ENV PORT 8000

RUN apt-get update
RUN groupadd -r tst && useradd -m -r -g tst tst

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD app /usr/src/app
ADD inc /tmp/inc

RUN npm install --production
RUN npm install /tmp/inc
RUN rm -rf /tmp/inc

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: Can you add your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you don't use `--unsafe-perm` npm key. Try change `npm install` to:

```
RUN npm install --production --unsafe-perm
```

Comment: it's not actually a permissions problem.  it's complaining about that because it's trying to write to the `node_modules/inc` directory but it can't because there's already a symlink there (because the `.dockerignore` was ignored and the `node_modules` directory was copied into the context)